# No response from my C# program

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, hardware

The program works by using speech recognition, and is based on Jarvis.. I want to be able to use different languages for the speech recognition, such as Danish and English. My problem is that I don't get any response. I cant seem to figure out if i get a response or even if the speech is detected and read.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    SpeechSynthesizer Dexter = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    string QEvent;
    string ProcWindow;
    double timer = 10;
    int count = 1;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Commands.txt")))));
        _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
        _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }

    void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        string speech = e.Result.Text;
        switch (speech)
        {
            //GREETINGS
            case "Hey Dexter":
            case "Hej Dexter":
                if (ranNum < 6) { Dexter.Speak("Hej sir"); }
                else if (ranNum > 5) { Dexter.Speak("Hej"); }
                break;

            case "Shut down Dexter":
            case "Luk ned Dexter":
                Dexter.Speak("Så ses vi");
                Close();
                break;

            case "Dexter":
                if (ranNum < 5) { QEvent = ""; Dexter.Speak("Ye sir"); }
                else if (ranNum > 4) { QEvent = ""; Dexter.Speak("Ye"); }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the speech recognition library, but it seems like if it doesn't recognize one of those 5 commands it won't do anything.  Have you debugged it to see if it recognizes _anything_?

Comment: Also, doing a `switch` on strings is considered a bad idea. Namely around case sensitivity and (since we're talking Danish) accents.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a workaround

Comment: First check your microphone is properly detected by the program. I had the same issue and found that it was the problem.